# How can I import two types with the same name from different modules?

Tags: rust

The [`rand_distr::Poisson`](https://docs.rs/rand_distr/0.4.0/rand_distr/struct.Poisson.html) struct provides some useful sampling code, whereas the [`statrs::distribution::Poisson`](https://docs.rs/statrs/0.13.0/statrs/distribution/struct.Poisson.html) struct provides other things like `pmf()` and so on.

I'd like to use both; is this possible?

```rust
use rand_distr::Poisson;
use statrs::distribution::Poisson;
```

has an error in vscode:

```
Error: the name `Poisson` is defined multiple times
label: previous import of the type `Poisson` here
note: `Poisson` must be defined only once in the type namespace of this module
label: previous import of the type `Poisson` here
warning: unused import: `rand_distr::Poisson`
```

And in particular cargo reports

```
error[E0252]: the name `Poisson` is defined multiple times
 --> src/main.rs:3:37
  |
1 | use rand_distr::{Poisson, Distribution};
  |                  ------- previous import of the type `Poisson` here
2 | use rand::distributions::Distribution;
3 | use statrs::distribution::{Discrete,Poisson};// as statrs_Poisson};
  |                                     ^^^^^^^ `Poisson` reimported here
```

All instances of `Poisson` in the code are now considered `statrs::distribution::Poisson`, even if I attempt to 'fully namespace them'.

```
let p_one = rand_distr::Poisson::new(rate_one_baseline).unwrap();
let v = p_one.sample(&mut rand::thread_rng());
```

fails, claiming there's no `sample` method.

## Solution

The answer below is the correct one. This example was complicated by *two* overlapping imports, so I had to rename two `use`.

```rust
//broke:
use rand_distr::{Poisson, Distribution};
use rand::distributions::Distribution; //provides pmf()
use statrs::distribution::{Discrete,Poisson};// implements Distribution
//ok:
use rand_distr::{Poisson, Distribution};
use rand::distributions::Distribution as _;
use statrs::distribution::{Discrete,Poisson as statrs_Poisson};
```

## Working example

```rust
use rand_distr::{Poisson, Distribution};
use rand::distributions::Distribution as _;
use statrs::distribution::{Discrete,Poisson as statrs_Poisson};
fn main() {

    let poi = rand_distr::Poisson::new(2.0).unwrap();
    let poi_statrs = statrs_Poisson::new(2.0).unwrap();
   
    //   rand_distr
    //yep:
    let x1 = poi.sample(&mut rand::thread_rng());
    //nope:
    //let _y1 = poi.pmf(0);
    println!("poi  1:{}", x1);

    //   statrs
    //yep:
    let x2 = poi_statrs.pmf(0);
    println!("poi  2:{}", x2);
    //nope:
    //let _y2 = poi_statrs.sample(&mut rand::thread_rng() ); 
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, **not the message produced by an IDE**, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a different name:

```
use rand_distr::Poisson;
use statrs::distribution::Poisson as statrs_Poisson;
```

Then when you want to use the second one (imported from `statrs`), use `statrs_Poisson`, not `Poisson`, like `statrs_Poisson::pmf()`.

Comment: Works as suggested. For those following the sample / pmf problem precisely, you also have to `use rand::distributions::Distribution as _;` because the functions are defined in that particular trait.